# SQL Server 2012 connection string works fine in classic ASP (VBScript) but doesn't work in ASP.NET C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a scenario just like below:

I have a **SQL Server Database** and I do make operations to SQL server from my **classic asp** project. I needed to do some other stuffs into the same DB from another project which is written in **ASP.NET C#**. I did use a host address in connection string which was provided by hosting provider(Say, the host address is **sqlxx.123xxx\inst_xyz**). They also provided an IP with a port to connect the DB, which only works in **SQL Server Management Studio**. In the webconfig of C# project if I use the IP then it connects from my local dev machine. But it doesn't work after deploying to hosting.

Again, if I use sqlxx.123xxx\inst_xyz as host address in classic ASP then it works. The IP doesn't work here. **My question is, host sqlxx.123xxx\inst_xyz works in classic ASP, IP works in ASP.NET C# in local IIS, but what will be the host for ASP.NET C# in hosting server ?**

**Please Note that, classic ASP project is in the main domain and ASP.NET C# project is in a sub domain of the main domain.**

If I use either of the hosts(sqlxx.123xxx\inst_xyz or IP), I get an error which states exactly like below :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)**

Comment: can you please show me your web config file?

Comment: Here is the link to webconfig : http://1drv.ms/1InCmnv

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77304/asp-connection-problem join here. will discuss it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this:

```
<add key="myCon" value="Server=this_my_host;database=dbname;User Id=myuser;Password=dbpass;"/>
```

and Remove `<connectionStrings>`.

If you are connecting with your Remote host then you must use the `<appSettings>` not the `<connectionStrings>` string.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these two:

1. Put a @ in front of your connection string: @"sqlxx.123xxx\inst_xy"
2. Double the `\` in the connection string, to `\\`: "sqlxx.123xxx\\inst_xy"

I'm thinking the backslash needs escaping.